# Add Sass option after creation of a project

Tags: sass, jhipster

Is there any way to generate a JHipster project **without** Sass option and **add** it later on?

I have tried to enable it via "*.yo-rc.json*" and then I run "*jhipster upgrade --force*", but it does not enable it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it while keeping your custom code using git.

Let's say your working code in on master (you could create a branch for experimenting), create a git branch to add saas

```
git checkout -b add-saas
```

Modify .yo-rc.json, re-generate your app using `jhipster --with-entities`

build your app, test it and commit if OK:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "Re-generated with saas"
```

then merge back to master:

```
git checkout master
git merge -s recursive Xours add-saas
```

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have created a new project with SASS option and I have made all the appropriate modifications to the old project manually.