# Issue with Jhipster upgrade from 4.5.2 to 4.14.1

Tags: jhipster

We are trying to upgrade our jhipster application to the latest version. 
 We are trying to upgrade manually as referred in the page [http://www.jhipster.tech/2018/02/27/jhipster-release-4.14.1.html][1]

currently our Jhipster version is 4.5.2

after executing the command

yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster

following is the output:

```
yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster
yarn global v1.5.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Rebuilding all packages...

info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
success Saved 0 new dependencies.
Done in 0.11s.
```

now if I check the Jhipster version it still shows 4.5.2

we want to upgrade to Jhipster 4.14.1

```
Other Version we use:
node version -> v8.9.4
npm version -> 5.6.0
yarn version -> 1.5.1
```

What is going wrong in our upgrade steps that we do?

Comment: Have you tryed with [yarn update](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you actually did not fully follow the release note.
Have you executed the second command ?

`jhipster upgrade`

EDIT: 
If you follow the manual way to update, then have you follow this instruction ?

> If you have an existing project, it will still use the JHipster
>   version with which it was generated. To upgrade your project, you must
>   first delete its node_modules folder and then run:
>
> ```
> jhipster
> ```

Comment: I want to follow the **Manual upgrades**

Comment: Then you might follow the instruction completely as well. I've edited my post accordingly

Comment: To re-generate a project with existing entities, you must use `jhipster --with-entities`. If you want to keep your custom code, you can try the approach I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009650/add-sass-option-after-creation-of-a-project